# What is wrong with my C++ Floyd's all-pairs shortest paths program?

Tags: c++, algorithm, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I am trying to find the all-pairs shortest paths matrix for a 5x5 matrix, but the output is not showing the right answer.

Here is the initial matrix and my output:

[image]

Here is the actual solution though:

```
[0, 2, 3, 1, 4, 

6, 0, 3, 2, 5

10, 12, 0, 4, 7,

6, 8, 2, 0, 3,

3, 5, 6, 4, 0]
```

As you can see, it reads the initial matrix correctly, but somewhere in the code, the math isn't being applied correctly, or something is messing up.

[Below is my code](http://pastebin.com/44wFwxfm), can you find my mistakes?

```
int matrixFloyd(int *C, int n, int *A, string* s)
{

  int i,j,k;

  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      if ( *(C+i*n+j) == -1)
      {
        *(A+i*n+j) = 999999999;
      }
      else
      {
        *(A+i*n+j) = 1;
        char sz[3]="";
        sprintf(sz,"%d",j+1);
        s[i*n+j]=sz;
      }
    }
  }

  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    *(A+i*n+i) = 0;
  }

  for (k=0; k<n; k++)
  {
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      for (j=0; j<n; j++)
      {
        if ( *(A+i*n+k) + *(A+k*n+j) < *(A+i*n+j) )

          // A[i][j] = A[i][k] + A[k][j];
          *(A+i*n+j) = *(A+i*n+k)+ *(A+k*n+j);
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring the original C values:

```
*(A+i*n+j) = 1;
```

Should be

```
*(A+i*n+j) = *(C+i*n+j);
```

Comment: Ok, so one last issue I have with this code: *(A+i*n+j) = 999999999;  Clearly, 99999999 isn't really infinite, but when I replace "99999999" with "(unsigned int)(-1)", it breaks the output.  I've also tried including <limits.h> and using INT_MAX and LONG_LONG_MAX, but neither of these works either.  Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: You can't use `INT_MAX` because then your addition `*(A+i*n+k) + *(A+k*n+j)` overflows and ends up being smaller than `*(A+i*n+j)`. Same applies for `LONG_LONG_MAX`

Comment: Ah, I see.  Is there any way to address the issue?  If not, it's no big deal!

Comment: Don't use `INT_MAX` ? A "large enough" value should suffice. If you really want to use it, cast the values to a wider data type before adding: `(long long)*(A+i*n+k) + ...`